# jHipster blank relation field on many-to-one

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am trying to do a not-just-plain-CRUD app on jHipster just for evaluation purposes and find a problem that maybe is related my inexperience on Angular:

Using generator i've created a many-to-one relationship between CustomerOrder and Customer.
I've choose to view the field "name" of the Customer as Relationship id in the view.
I've created a new Customer and created a new CustomerOrder, selecting the customer from a combobox (thats nice).

Problem now is i do not see any value in the Customer field on the CustomerOrder view.
I see that API response is ok. It retrieves a CustomerObject JSON with an embedded Customer object that has value setted in "name" property so i guess it's a problem on the angular side.

However i've not changed anything so i expect it to works since i created this using generator.

This is the code on the angular view.
NOTE that i can see the value in details form, but not in the list

customerOrder-detail.html:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span translate="hipsterspikeApp.customerOrder.Customer">Customer</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" value="{{customerOrder.customer.name}}" readonly>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

customerOrders.html:

```
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label translate="hipsterspikeApp.customerOrder.Customer">Customer</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="Customer" ng-model="customerOrder.customer.id" ng-options="customer.id as customer.name for customer in customers">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

This is the response ...

[{"id":1,"code":"o1","comments":"o1","delivered":null,"expecedAt":null,"customer":{"id":1,"name":"c1","address":"c1","comments":"c1","email":"c1","phone":"c1"},"items":null}]

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am having a similar problem.